# Multiple AND/OR Query Not Yielding Correct Results

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, conditional-statements

The following is sample data:

```
FamID|Dad    |Mom    |Son    |
------------------------------
1    |John   |Mary   |Barry  |
2    |Bob    |Jane   |Donald |
3    |Sam    |Jessica|Sam Jr |
4|   |Jason  |Nancy  |Conway |
5    |Steve  |Sara   |JR     |
6    |John   |Bonnie |Ron    |
```

The following is what the result should be:

```
FamID|Dad    |Mom    |Son    |
------------------------------
1    |John   |Bonnie |Ron    |
```

The following is a sample query of what I am doing:

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    Family
WHERE
    (Dad != 'John' AND Mom != 'Mary')
    AND
    (Dad != 'Bob' AND Mom != 'Jane')
    AND
    (Dad != 'Sam' AND Mom != 'Jessica')
    AND 
    (Dad != 'Jason' AND Mom != 'Nancy')
    AND
    (Dad != 'Steve' AND Mom != 'Sara')`
```

This query is excluding results that shouldn't be excluded.  Is my syntax wrong?

Comment: give us sample data, real output and desired output

Comment: btw, ansi sql defines operator "not equal" as `<>`, but t-sql allows `!=` as well

Comment: the fact that you grouped the `AND` blocks like that doesn't mean that combinations are allowed, e.g. if there are parents John and Jane in the same Family row they will be filtered out by the `where` clause even though they are part of "different" `AND` conditions

Comment: Im on SQL Server 2012...is this not t-sql?

Comment: Replace ANDs outside parentheses with ORs

Comment: @JeffOrris T-SQL is the SQL dialect used in SQL Server (all versions). T-SQL itself changes as the SQL Server version changes. But the language is still T-SQL.

Comment: @peter.petrov `<>` is yielding the same results

Comment: @JeffOrris Seems you have a logical mistake here, not a syntactical one. Think about the logic i.e. about the ANDs/ORs etc, not about the syntax.

Comment: @Mihai `OR` is yielding the same results.  Should I use `NOT IN`?

Comment: Is the space between ! = a typo?

Comment: what country has a "1 son" policy? :)

Comment: @Mihai.  Yes, that must have been typo...I will fix it.  Isn't white space ignored anyways though?

Comment: @myte lol...I actually just got that

Comment: With OR outside parentheses what are the results on your sample data?It should work

Comment: @Mihai  Same results

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is what you need here:

```
SELECT *
FROM   Family
WHERE  NOT ( 
             ( Dad = 'John'  AND Mom = 'Mary' )
          OR ( Dad = 'Bob'   AND Mom = 'Jane' )
          OR ( Dad = 'Sam'   AND Mom = 'Jessica' )
          OR ( Dad = 'Jason' AND Mom = 'Nancy' )
          OR ( Dad = 'Steve' AND Mom = 'Sara' ) 
           )
```

This is logically the same as:

```
SELECT *
FROM   Family
WHERE  (     
             ( Dad <> 'John'  OR Mom <> 'Mary' )
         AND ( Dad <> 'Bob'   OR Mom <> 'Jane' )
         AND ( Dad <> 'Sam'   OR Mom <> 'Jessica' )
         AND ( Dad <> 'Jason' OR Mom <> 'Nancy' )
         AND ( Dad <> 'Steve' OR Mom <> 'Sara' ) 
       )
```

Comment: Why does the `WHERE NOT` work and the logically same not work?

Comment: @Jeff: I think you may not have noticed that the query here has ORs inside the parenthesis, whereas the query you listed originally has ANDs inside and outside the parenthesis.

Answer (score 0):

In your where clause you are excluding "john" so off course you will not get what you want.
Beside you are fetching data in a wrong way, you must depend on familyID.
Suspose you have thousands of records in your table, will you add thousand condition!! This is very week.
Never depend on text always try to use id.

Comment: I'm an intern and learning.  There are MILLIONS of rows of data Im pouring through.  There are only a few business rules to it though.  This is actually just an Execute SQL task in an SSIS package. This was a stage table with NO PK as well as just an example table that only had relevance to what I was trying to do.  Also...relook at the conditions.